# unique id for window/tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, browser

For example,
 consider the following, a browser gets open  first with single tab then a unique id should assign for the opened tab, the tabId should persist across any number of pages redirects happen on the tab ( tabId should be there till the tab gets close), like that any new tab open means also it should have unique Id in same manner.

Note:
1. No extensions
2. Not using window.name property
3. can use html5 features like localStorage, sessionStorage etc...

I need to associate tabIds with tabs got opened by the time, if any action or navigations(redirects) of pages happen under particular tab, then I need to get alert of  tabId of the tab.

I am need of this in very critical time slot, plz anybody have any logic or idea on this? I would like to appreciate in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You could use this function to always get a different id (accross a given domain) :

```
function getNewId() {
   var lastId = localStorage['lastId'] || '0';
   var newId = parseInt(lastId, 10) + 1;
   localStorage['lastId'] = newId;
   return newId;
}
```

Comment: thanks lot, your solution could generate uniqueId when it is getting call, its fine. But I need to associate Ids with tabs got opened by the time, if any action or navigations(redirects) of pages happen under particular tab, then I need to get alert of the tabId of the tab.